# E:\ This file does not have a program associated with it for performing this action. When the USB drive is inserted in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, usb

Whenever I insert a USB drive a message *"E:\ This file does not have a program associated with it for performing this action. Please install a program or, if one is already installed, create an association in the Default Apps Settings page"*

[image]

I haven't found a working solution yet, a working solution would be appreciated.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I tried scanning the system for errors, I tried a registry fix here: HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Lnkfile as well

Comment: Please add a list of the files on the root of the USB, meaning at E:\

Comment: @harrymc You mean extensions: It has 2 `.zip` folders, 1 `.pptx` and 1 `.pdf` file

Comment: Ensure you can see hidden files in Explorer *View > Options > View > Hidden f‌iles and folders*.

Comment: @harrymc hidden view is enabled and I can only see those files I mentioned

Comment: Have you set anything in *Settings > Devices > AutoPlay*, under "Choose AutoPlay defaults" for "Removable drive"?

Comment: Yes it seems there is an option: "Import photos and videos (Dropbox)"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145169/discussion-between-xavier-fakerat-and-harrymc).

Comment: Have you tried to change the setting "*Import photos and videos ( Dropbox )*" into "*Open folder to view files ( File Explorer )*" ? This is worrisome, since this could be an execution of a malicious software. Also, the red X looks funny.

Comment: You can also run CMD, there type "*CD E:*" to change the directory into E drive, then run the command "*dir*" to view a list of files. If that works, we can make the CLI to copy your files to your local drive like that "*cp * c:\Temp*"

Comment: @Netan Thanks, I have chosen the option "Open folder to view files ( File Explorer )", will observe for a few days and see hoe it goes..

Comment: Then, it is working. Isn't it?

Comment: @Netan Much thanks, that seems to have solved this issue :)

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help! I'm actually new here and don't know if I should write it as an answer... Ahhhh nvm that, let's live on the edge.

Comment: @Netan yes please go ahead and I will accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has already fixed the problem but I'll answer for future queries:

Try to change the setting `Import photos and videos ( Dropbox )` into `Open folder to view files ( File Explorer )`

You can also run CMD, there type "CD E:" to change the directory into E drive, then run the command "dir" to view a list of files. If that works, we can make the CLI to copy your files to your local drive like that ( run it while in the same CMD window! If you open a new one, first navigate to the drive using `cd` command ) :

`cp * c:\Temp`